# HTTP Live Streaming like UStream and Wowza GoCoder app

Tags: wowza

I have to upload live video to wowza server. I don't have any idea about live streaming. I read apple document for HTTP Live streaming still I am not getting how to live stream video. Some one please help me on this.

Using AVFoundation I can get video Buffer/frames while recording

I am trying to upload the frames to the server. How to do the uploading part?

Answer (score 0):

You should read this support article from Wowza to see what to do: http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?37-How-to-publish-and-play-a-live-stream-(MPEG-TS-based-encoder)